# Are there examples of AI systems that use grammatical rules in order to recognize commands in natural language?

Tags: natural-language-processing, reference-request

Are there examples of AI systems that use grammatical rules in order to recognize commands in natural language?

For example, is there a program, when given the instruction (either by speech or by text) in the form of "Open file-1", will attempt to understand the command as consisting the parts "open" and "file-1", then respond according to how each part is classified?

The focus here is the fact that these kind of instructions are processed with built-in rules of grammar, rather than the rules being learned through observation of data.

Comment: old text adventures? How "natural" does the natural language processing need to be to count as an example for you, and how flexible?

Comment: More general than text-adventure; in terms of flexibility, if there is limitation to the variety of sentence forms that the AI can process due to the fact that it has built-in rules, I'd like to know more.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  You're basically looking for "rule based" NLP.  For reference, see:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule-based_system
- https://www.quora.com/Why-are-rule-based-methods-becoming-unpopular-in-NLP-Are-rule-based-methods-still-in-use-If-yes-where-should-I-look-for-them
- https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3756254/
- https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/regexner.html
- [http://u.cs.biu.ac.il/~yogo/courses/sem2014/intro.pdf](http://u.cs.biu.ac.il/%7Eyogo/courses/sem2014/intro.pdf)